# I want build a alert for ema indicator crypto in a special list

Tags: python, websocket, cryptocurrency

First one:

```
    ### configuration details 
    TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '' # telegram bot token 
    TELEGRAM_CHANNEL ='' # channel id 
    INTERVAL = '1m' # binance time interval 
    SHORT_EMA = 7 # short interval for ema 
    LONG_EMA = 21 # long interval for ema
```

Here is my second code:

```
import requests
import talib 
import time 
import numpy as np 
import websocket

 
from config import TELEGRAM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_CHANNEL , INTERVAL, SHORT_EMA , LONG_EMA 

def streamKline(currency, interval):
    websocket.enableTrace(False)
    socket = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{currency}@kline_{interval}'
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket)

    ws.run_forever()

#SYMBOLS TO LOOK FOR ALERTS 
SYMBOLS = [
    "ETHUSDT",
    "BTCUSDT",
    "ATOMUSDT",
    "BNBUSDT",
    "FTMBUSD",
    "ENJUSDT",
    "WAXPUSDT"
]


#sending alerts to telegram 
def send_message(message):
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}&parse_mode=markdown".format(TELEGRAM_TOKEN,TELEGRAM_CHANNEL,message)
    res = requests.get(url);print(url);
    return res

# getting klines data to process
def streamKline(symbol):
    data = socket.streamKline(symbol=symbol,interval=INTERVAL,limit=300) # more data means more precision but at the trade off between speed and time 
    return_data = []
    # taking closing data for each kline 
    for each in data:
        return_data.append(float(each[4])) # 4 is the index of the closing data in each kline 
    return np.array(return_data) # returning as numpy array for better precision and performance 

 
def main(): 
    # making a infinite loop that keeps checking for condition 
    while True:
        #looping through each coin 
        for each in SYMBOLS:
            data = streamKline(each)
            ema_short = talib.EMA(data,int(SHORT_EMA))
            ema_long = talib.EMA(data,int(LONG_EMA))
            
            last_ema_short  = ema_short[-2]
            last_ema_long = ema_long[-2]

            ema_short = ema_short[-1]
            ema_long = ema_long[-1]
        
            # conditions for alerts 
            if(ema_short > ema_long and last_ema_short < last_ema_long):
                message  = each + "bullcoming "+ str(SHORT_EMA) + " over "+str(LONG_EMA);print(each ,"alert came");
                send_message(message);
            time.sleep(0.5);


# calling the function 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The part of config is all settle done, just second for the kline data, the error mention lot like this.

```
  data = socket.streamKline(symbol=symbol,interval=INTERVAL,limit=300) # more data means more precision but at the 
trade off between speed and time
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
```

I just don't know how to do it, I want build a ema alert that can give me a message when I am not watching chart, through this way seems not work, I have tried many times, and also find many video but still, I am just an beginner, nothing improving at all.

Comment: You imported websocket.  Did you want to use ```websocket.streamKline(...```?

Comment: Can you please update your question title and text to reference the most specific issue you're seeking help with?

Comment: i just want this script can be use as ema crypto alert, behonest guys i am really unknown for these knowledge

Comment: i can be sure is , first one is worked, just second one i cant get the data

Comment: @ewokx, yes, but seems i screw it up haha